# Required 26.8mm diameter Seat Post

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension, seatpost, hybrid-bike

I have a Schwinn Searcher Sport 2011 Hybrid Bike, with a damaged seat post.

Thus, I require a 26.8mm seat post with suspension. In India, I have searched, but I am not able to find a suitable seat post.

How can I obtain a suitable seat post?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Inspireaman. Please read through the [help] to learn how this site works. You don't really ask a question that can be answered, but if we guess that you're asking for a product recommendation then the question would be off topic because product recommendations go out of date quickly. Try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=26.8mm+Seatpost+suspension).

Comment: You can sometimes get away with using a smaller post and a shim.

Comment: Seatpost sizes are well standardized -- that is to say, there are about 20 different "standards".  There are a few odd sizes that are quite hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest any site like Amazon, EBay, or craigslist even. I just skimmed through and Amazon, as well as EBay have a good assortment of seat posts in that size.

If you want an actual bike shop website, try using Wiggle. It is something of a surplus store, so they have a pretty decent selection at decent prices.

Your seat post size seems to be fairly common, so I don't think you should have any problems finding something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A fast look at [bikecomponents](https://www.bike-components.de/en/Cane-Creek/Thudbuster-LT-Sattelstuetze-400-mm-p7468/). Look at the **SUSPENSION SEATPOST** section.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go smaller and shim it up with aluminum cans.

EDIT: I removed the suggestion to get a 27.2 and remove .2 mm of material.

Comment: I'd not recommend removing metal from a structural item like a seat post.  Seems to be asking for problems.  Plus its incredibly hard to keep it round.